# Facebook Comment Logic

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

Hi Like in facebook you can comment on the post and reply to specific comment.Can anyone please  tell me what technique is used like table view inside the table view or they have different cell.

Comment: what makes you think they even use a tableview?

Comment: Do you have any idea that kind of hierarchy? @luk2302
I guess this can be achieved using the tableview.

Comment: could be tableviews, but I m not sure about scrolling for a cell with tableview. They could have possibly implemented their own tableview like UI element. They seems to have time with coming up with complete framework to develop hybrid apps, so yeah maybe they sub classed scroll view like UITableView does.